# What is the most massive single piece of matter created with 50% chance in the lifetime of the visible universe due to quantum vacuum fluctuations?

Tags: cosmology, vacuum

Quantum vacuum fluctuations are said to be able to spontaneously generate matter at a very low probability. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_far_future) reports a Boltzman Brain would take 10^10^50 years to appear in the vacuum.

What is the largest mass created due single spontaneous generation of matter that has a 50% chance of having occurred (since 100% is not possible) to-date in the visible universe?

Conversely, what are the chances of a sperm whale or bowl of petunias having been spontaneously generated?

Comment: On a related note, I'm reading "The Quantum Universe: Everything that Can Happen, Does"  In it he asks the question "How long will we have to wait for for their to be a reasonable probability that a grain of sand will hop outside of a matchbox?"    The answer is 6 x 10^13 years, or a thousand times the age of the universe.

Comment: Excellent example - thus the answer is likely much smaller than that -- I am even wondering if a single proton has ever been created to-date (much less a sperm whale or a bowl of petunias).

Comment: Normally Boltzmann brains are attributed to *thermal* fluctuations -- random rearrangements of existing matter. In quantum field theory, the probability to transition from the vacuum state to a state with particles is zero. So I'm not sure if I understand the process you are referring to, do you have a source? To get particle creation, you need something dramatic to happen, such as the event horizon of a black hole (Hawking radiation), or a time-dependent background spacetime like in inflation, or a vacuum decay event.

Comment: Well I dont quite have the physics to say, though I've read of this concept before several times - and that wikipedia article says "from the vacuum" -- and as far as I've read about Boltzman Brains, the postulated exercise is usually the brain appearing spontaneously in the vacuum as I recall.